# How to show a form when a button is clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

In the application i'm coding in C#, i right clicked on my project on solution explorer, then gone to Add, then selected Windows Forms and selected Windows Forms and pressed Ok!

Then i named my Form MessageForm instead of the default name ( Form2 )

Now in my form one i added a button, i wanted this button to show me the other form ( MessageForm) when i click on it so my code was :

```
 MessageForm Frm = new MessageForm();
        Frm.Show();
```

But there was an error and i couldn't compile the code, because i'm getting the following :

```
 Error  1   The type or namespace name 'MessageForm' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How could this be ?

Comment: Always refactor your code when renaming

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you only have renamed the `Form2.cs` file to `MessageForm.cs` but not the actual type name inside this file. Before clicking OK in the Add Windows Form dialog you should replace `Form2.cs` with `MessageForm.cs`. This way the file and the type will be named correctly. But if the form already exists you could navigate to the corresponding file and replace:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

with:

```
public partial class MessageForm : Form
{
    public MessageForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, and do not forget `MessageForm.Designer.cs`. You might have to change the class name there manually too.